# Give an example of a set $A$ and a function $f\colon A \to A$ where $f$ is onto but not one-to-one.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am currently trying to decipher this question but I have been unable to thus far. If a set $A$ is mapped onto itself, it seems that you would always have a function that is both onto and one-to-one. My only idea is that this may be vacuously true for a set $A$ such that $A = \{\varnothing\}$. Is this a true assumption, or is there another example that holds true for this problem?

Comment: This will *not* work for the empty set, or any finite set for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Take $A$ to be an infinite set; $\Bbb N$ will work well. It’s impossible with a finite set.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the mapping $\beta\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by
$$
\beta(n)=
\begin{cases}
(n+1)/2&\text{if $n$ is odd},\\
n/2&\text{if $n$ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$
Can you see why $\beta$ is onto but not one-to-one? It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: You can map multiple values of set 1 into set 2. You do this all the time, the function y = x squared maps both +1 and -1 to the value 1. Or sin(x) maps 0, pi, 2*pi, 3*pi etc to the same value of 0. The reason he does this is because this is what the question asks - a mapping which is onto but not one-to-one (which means two values from set 1 are mapped to the same value in set 2).